# [pytest + allure]: customize (add custom labels) to test's history

Tags: pytest, allure

using pytest + allure

```
allure-pytest         2.9.45
allure-python-commons 2.9.45
```

Is there any ability to customize test's history in the report?
[image]

Instead of time or nearby add more info f.e. some custom labels / fields